# Change in travel plans after UK Tier 2 ICT visa issued

Tags: united-kingdom, usa, indian-citizens

I have obtained my Tier 2 ICT long-term employment visa while in the USA. Since I am an Indian citizen and hold an Indian passport, I would like to travel to India from the USA, and then travel to the UK. I shall ensure that I report within the 30-day period.

Is this possible, as I have mentioned "Will be travelling from the USA" when I submitted my Tier 2 visa application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine.  Plans change all the time, and the UK knows it.  Visas do not depend on a particular point of departure, so changing the point of departure is not significant.